# Access query need 'last full week'

Tags: ms-access

In this query- The user has to enter the from and to dates. Is there a facility to give me the dates as 'in last full week', Because this query is used for staff meeting every Friday. They deal with all cases from the previous week which is Monday thru Saturday. I would like to automate this to be scheduled that is why.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter From Date:] Text ( 255 ), [Enter To Date:] Text ( 255 );
TRANSFORM Count([Staff Programs].ID) AS CountofProgram
SELECT [Staff Programs].program_name
FROM [Staff Programs]
WHERE ((([Staff Programs].is_noshow)=No) AND (([Staff Programs].[Event_Name]) Not In ('Phone Contact - (Client)','Session Preparation','Research','Clinician Travel','Reporting','Collateral Contact','Correspondence','Data Entry')) AND (([Staff Programs].actual_date) Between [Enter From date:] And [Enter To Date:]))
GROUP BY [Staff Programs].program_name
PIVOT [Staff Programs].staff_name;
```

Comment: Select * from table where date between date1 and date2

Comment: but that would mean user input ? i want something to run automatically.

Comment: Save a “timestamp”?

Comment: that's not bad. I would have a small table that has the dates. I was thinking like in crystal reports they have 'lastfullweek' so it takes only the dates automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
TRANSFORM Count([Staff Programs].ID) AS CountofProgram
SELECT [Staff Programs].program_name
FROM [Staff Programs]
WHERE ((([Staff Programs].is_noshow)=No) AND (([Staff Programs].[Event_Name]) Not In ('Phone Contact - (Client)','Session Preparation','Research','Clinician Travel','Reporting','Collateral Contact','Correspondence','Data Entry')) AND (([Staff Programs].actual_date) Between Date() - ( 6 + Weekday(Date(), 2)) And Date() - Weekday(Date(), 1)))
GROUP BY [Staff Programs].program_name
PIVOT [Staff Programs].staff_name;
```

Comment: Thanks, so that is I must run it on a Friday ? that is fine.

Comment: Whenever you run this query, it will fetch data for previous week ( mon to sat)